# Cyberoam Internet Issue

Tags: security

I have a security problem on my network, sometimes some computers are disconecting from internet, when i visualised log files of my cyberoam , i found in top domains some adresses not recognised  like :

- bfm-vh.akamaihd.net
- akmedia.shahid.net

is that can be considered as an attack ?
if yes what are the solutions of that ? 
Thanks by advance

Comment: these look like ad servers, just scan those machines with adware cleaner and see what happens, the internet dropping issue looks like something else